# svn folder added in trunk and branch, how to resolve conflict

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I using SVN (with a TortoiseSVN client) and have added the same folder in a trunk and a branch. I've added them individually, which is why I have a tree conflict now. I'm aware that I shouldn't have done that, but that doesn't help me much now, that I'm in this situation. The folders are meant to represent the same content. Most files are the same, a few would need to be merged. Everywhere I looked it is suggested to deal with this problem "manually". But I wonder how to go about it, this is my idea:

- SVN-export the folder from the branch
- SVN-delete the folder from the branch, commit the branch
- SVN-merge trunk into branch and thereby have the folder back again, but now the version from the trunk
- merging BY HAND the exported folder into the branch, commit
- work on the branch...
- merge the branch back into the trunk (when finished with it)

Is this what you would do, or do you have a better suggestion?

Comment: Where are you having the problem; Merging the trunk into the branch or reintegrating the branch into the trunk?

Comment: merging the trunk into the branch

Comment: Reverse-merge revision, which added folder into branch

Answer (score 0):

Using tortoise, I'd do the merge (trunk into branch), and then manually work through the conflicts merging files and fixing tree-conflicts in directories. Then commit and move on.

As you said, the best method was to put them in one location, then merge them across into the other.

**Disclaimer:** I've not done the reverse-merge that Lazy Badger is proposing. That may be easier. See comments.

Comment: Read docs better - http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html "Undoing Changes" chapter

Comment: "Undoing Changes" != "Reverse merge". Hard to find without knowing what you are looking for. Answer updated.

Comment: "Undoing committed changes" == "Reverse merge" in SVN-world